# How to create jCheckBox depending on number of rows present in database?

Tags: java, database, swing

I want to create a frame in java with variable number of checkboxes which will depend on the number of rows present in my database.
Problems that I am facing are:-
1. How to count the number of rows in database?
2. How and where to store the data present in columns of database?
3. How to create checkboxes with that data present in column of database?

Can anyone help me.??
Looking forward for solution.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try something. You'll need lists and loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to count the number of rows in table?

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name;

> How and where to store the data present in columns of database?

I would suggest you to use [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) and look the tutorial [How to use Table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

> How to create checkboxes with that data present in column of
>   database?

Read about [Renderer and Editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) section to know more about registered cell renderers in `JTable`.